# Issue with GROK match for access logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am getting a grokparsefailure on some of these apache logs, that is not making sense to me. One of the kibana tags for these is the grokparsefailure. Obviously something is wrong here but I am having trouble figuring out what that is. 
Example log entry that resulted in a failure:

```
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Oct/2016:19:05:54 +0000] "POST /v1/api/query.random HTTP/1.1" 201 - "-" "-"  188
```

Logstash output config file:

```
filter {
 if [type] == "access" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
}
filter {
 if [type] == "requests" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://ESCLUSTER:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "[type]"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Comment: With multiple grok{} statements, add a unique tag_on_failure parameter to each one.  That will tell you which one is failing and hopefully give you more  guidance to fix the problem.

Comment: This is the requests one. Sorry for not giving that earlier, but I already was aware of which one it was as the "type" is also logged in es so I can see the type that matches the grokpatternfailure.

Answer (score 0):

There are two spaces instead of one between the two `-` and between the `-` and the `[`: `127.0.0.1 -  -  [`.

The [pattern](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/6116ef4cbbb9d66b0ec81dfc68f6aa0ed0aa076d/patterns/httpd#L5) (`%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth}`) expect only one space at this points.

So either you correct your log format so that all logs are of the same format, or you replace `%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}` by

```
%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident}%{SPACE}%{HTTPDUSER:auth}%{SPACE}\[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}
```

This pattern is equivalent to the `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` pattern, but I replace the space at the beginning by the `%{SPACE}` pattern which match one or more space.